# WPF XAML x:Name="[Anything]" causes compilation to fail with "Type 'MyType' is not defined"

Tags: wpf, xaml, namespaces

Hi I am having trouble using a WPF UserControl inside another UserControl. I insert it in a Grid control like this:

```
<local:MultiUseDialog />
```

and it works and compiles fine but as soon as I add a name (any name) like this:

```
<local:MultiUseDialog x:Name="AnyNameWhatsoever" />
```

I get multiple compilation errors saying
**Error 7 - Type 'MyProject.MultiUseDialog' is not defined.**

What am I doing wrong? I am pulling my hair out here, any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: Did you try a clean and rebuild of the solution?

Comment: @Erno Yes, clean and rebuild did nothing, I have tried Rebuild Solution at least 30 times while trying various things. Very odd.

Comment: Could you share a minimal version of the code/solution that we can test? Have a look at this too: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/0f264b70-8f03-4adf-8ff6-24b1d7032dbf

Comment: I am amazed that I guessed right but also glad that it fixed the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A wild guess that speaks of the same error:

[Namespace issues](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/0f264b70-8f03-4adf-8ff6-24b1d7032dbf)

Comment: Thanks very much for the link, that helped me fix my project. It came down to duplicate namespaces like MyNameSpace.MyNameSpace.ViewModels, which when corrected, made the project work again. Thanks again!